# Jquery how can i grab the current url and change a query parameter

Tags: jquery

The current url

```
   http://www.example.com/search/?accommodation=1&venue=&seating=2&min=&max=&feature_list=7|8|9
```

Is there a way in jquery how can i grab my url which is this one above.... and the feature_list parameter change its value **(7|8|9)** to something like **8|9|10** ?

I dont need to change the URL header, just I want to link this output to an HREF..

This is what I want to achieve from the current URL.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/search/?accommodation=1&venue=&seating=2&min=&max=&feature_list=8|9|10">Link</a>
```

I am using this as a filtering system...

This is a dynamic url so 7|8|9 changes all the time...

Comment: elclanrs got the answer. If you want to do more "advanced" query parameter operations, you could try this plugin: [link](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) - which provide some great tools for editing, adinng parameters :)

Comment: its a good idea though I am trying to find a way how to regex a particular parameter, but cannot :(

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) .. But the Query plugin makes it much easir for you to get/set the parameters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.href.replace('7|8|9', '8|9|10'),
    $link = $('<a href="'+ url +'">Link</a>');
```

Comment: since the url is dynamic I cannot just replace 789 with 8910... because this changes all the time... maybe i need some kid of regex for the parameter ?

Comment: @MRR, maybe you need to polish your question.

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the best solution, but..

```
var urla = window.location.search.replace('?','').split('&');

$.each(urla, function(j,v)
{
  v=v.split('=');

  if(v[0]=='feature_list')
  {
    var ft=parseInt(v[1].replace(/.*\|/, ''));
    var fts=[];

    for(var i=ft-1; i<ft+2; i++)
      fts.push(i);

    urla[j]=v[0]+'='+(fts.join(','));
  }  
});

urla = '?'+urla.join('&');
$link = $('<a/>',{'href':urla}).text('Link');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  query = 'feature_list'    
  query = query.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
        var expr = "[\\?&]"+query+"=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp( expr );
        var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
        if( results !== null ) {
            return  results[1];
            return   decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
```

This function i found will return the value of a certain parameter given at the top

and then used elclanrs solution and did

```
 url = window.location.href.replace(ans, '8|9|10'),
 window.location.href = url;
```